# How can I use openjphjs with next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a project that uses Next.js. I need to use [openjphjs](https://github.com/chafey/openjphjs?tab=readme-ov-file#readme) to decode HTJ2K pixel data.

I added openjphjs.js and openjphjs.wasm to a folder in the project.

I also added the following to next.config.js.

```
    webpack: (config) => {
        config.resolve.fallback = { fs: false };
        return config;
    },
```

This was done to resolve the following error.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
```

I followed the example in [example](https://github.com/chafey/openjphjs/blob/master/test/node/index.js) and tried the following.

```
import openjphjs from './openjphjs/openjphjs.js';

const = decode = () => {
   const decoder = new openjphjs.HTJ2KDecoder();
}
```

Multiple errors were thrown.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/openjphjs.wasm 404 (Not Found)
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: Aborted(RuntimeError: Aborted(both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed).
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: _openjphjs_openjphjs_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8___default(...).HTJ2KDecoder is not a constructor
```

I tried manually placing openjphjs.wasm in path shown.
I also tried placing the files in the /public folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it a go within an app router project with Next.js 14.1.1 and got it instanced on the client with these steps, see if it can help:

1. Place both `openjphjs.js` and `openjphjs.wasm` in your `/public` directory
2. Create a server page route (I went for `app/openjph/page.tsx`):

```
import Openjph from "@/components/openjph/open";
import Script from "next/script";

export default async function Page(props) {
  return <>
    <Script
      strategy="beforeInteractive"
      src="/openjphjs.js"
    />
    <Openjph />
  </>
}
```

3. Create a client component (I went for `app/components/openjph/open.tsx`):

```
"use client";

import { useEffect } from 'react';

const Openjph = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
      try {
        const decoder = new Module.HTJ2KDecoder();
        console.log(decoder);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <>[...more stuff...]</>
  );
};

export default Openjph;
```

This oughta print the instanced decoder:
[image: OpenJPHjs decoder]

And proceed as needed. My `tsconfig.json` has something along these lines:

```
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["app/components/*"],
    },
```

Alternatively, you can simply import the `Openjph` component with relative paths or however you prefer.

EDIT:
If the above were not to work in a production build, here's a workaround for the `useEffect` hook:

```
[...]
// @ts-nocheck
[...]
```

```
 useEffect(() => {
    try {
      const decoder = new Module.HTJ2KDecoder();
      console.log("has a constructor: ", decoder);
    } catch (error) {
      try {
        console.log("doesn't have a a constructor yet");
        Module.onRuntimeInitialized = async () => {
          const decoder = new Module.HTJ2KDecoder();
          console.log("now it does", decoder);
          const encoder = new Module.HTJ2KEncoder();
          console.log(encoder);
        };
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: No problem, I've double-checked while in a production build and you can make use of ```onRuntimeInitialized``` like I've added in the EDIT if the `Module` errors out